# Select query payment schedule

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table on the payment schedule:

```
| PaySum   | PlanDate   |
+----------+------------+ 
| 23928.38 | 14.10.2019 |
| 24347.13 | 12.11.2019 |
| 24773.20 | 12.12.2020 |
| 25206.73 | 13.01.2020 |
```

Need to pull forthcoming amount for 3 months

My request for example:

```
select sum(s.PaySum)
  from L_DEA s
 where s.PlanDate between trunc(sysdate + 1) and
       ADD_months(trunc(sysdate + 1), 3)
   and ID = :iId;
```

This query returns 4 months if run sysdate = 12.10.19 or 13.10.19
in other cases shows correctly for 3 months

How to form select correctly

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try changing the inequality:

```
SELECT SUM(s.PaySum)
FROM L_DEA s
WHERE
    s.PlanDate >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND
    s.PlanDate < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1), 3) AND
    ID = :iId;
```

This would include all plan dates on or after midnight of today, but *before* midnight of three months from now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with you. At least in the given sample data, It is working correctly.

For 12-Oct-2019

```
SQL> with L_DEA (PaySum, PlanDate) as
  2  (select 23928.38 , to_date('14.10.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
  3  select 24347.13 , to_date('12.11.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
  4  select 24773.20 , to_date('12.12.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
  5  select 24773.20 , to_date('10.02.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all -- added this
  6  select 25206.73 , to_date('13.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual )
  7  select * --sum(s.PaySum)
  8    from L_DEA s
  9   where s.PlanDate between trunc(date '2019-10-12' + 1) and
 10         ADD_months(trunc(date '2019-10-12' + 1), 3)
 11     --and ID = :iId;

    PAYSUM PLANDATE
---------- ---------
  23928.38 14-OCT-19
  24347.13 12-NOV-19
  25206.73 13-JAN-20

SQL>
```

for another date i.e. 13-Oct-2019

```
SQL> with L_DEA (PaySum, PlanDate) as
  2  (select 23928.38 , to_date('14.10.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
  3  select 24347.13 , to_date('12.11.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
  4  select 24773.20 , to_date('12.12.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
  5  select 24773.20 , to_date('10.02.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all -- added this
  6  select 25206.73 , to_date('13.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual )
  7  select * --sum(s.PaySum)
  8    from L_DEA s
  9   where s.PlanDate between trunc(date '2019-10-13' + 1) and
 10         ADD_months(trunc(date '2019-10-13' + 1), 3)
 11     --and ID = :iId;

    PAYSUM PLANDATE
---------- ---------
  23928.38 14-OCT-19
  24347.13 12-NOV-19
  25206.73 13-JAN-20

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

One abbreviate option to cover the period starting from `the present day` to `three months` later would be :

```
select sum(s.PaySum)
  from l_dea s
 where s.PlanDate between trunc(systimestamp) and trunc(systimestamp) + interval '3' month
   and ID = :iId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.PlanDate, s.PaySum
  from L_DEA s
 inner join (select PlanDate
               from (select distinct s.PlanDate
                       from L_DEA s
                      where  ID = :iId
                        and s.PlanDate >= (to_date('10.10.2019'))
                      order by s.PlanDate) tt
              where rownum <= 3) A2
    on s.PlanDate = A2.PlanDate
 where ID = :iId);
```

Comment: prefer using `row_number()` instead of `rownum` whenever you need a generated sequence column. If an `ORDER BY` clause follows `ROWNUM` in the same query, then the rows will be reordered by the `ORDER BY` clause. The results can vary depending on the way the rows are accessed.